Background image doesn't show up (Flutter application)
I have some issues with my background image since it didn't show up on my application. I updated my pubspec yalm and added images to my assets directory, but only the logo image showed up. Can anyone explain for me pls? appreciate a lot
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../components/login_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class LogInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogInPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SafeArea(
             child: Column(
                children: [
                   Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/login_background.png"),
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                     )
                   ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),

                  const Text("Cục An toàn Thông tin",
                  style: TextStyle(
                     fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                  ),
                  ),

                  const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/login_logo.png"),
                  width: 80),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10),

                  const MyTextField(),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10),

                  const MyTextField()

            ],

           )
        ),
      )
    );

  }
}

My pubspec yalm
  assets:
    - assets/images/login_background.png
    - assets/images/login_logo.png

Here is my expected result
enter image description here
My current result has no background image

your container doest have any child or size. so the image doest have dimension.
solution: use the image as child of the container, or set the height and width to your container. it will disply the image.

wait I think that the problem is about the Container widget right? I don't have the child requirement so it might affect the background image right?

but if you want to make it as background, i recommend use the Stack

I used the image as the child of container widget, but it still doesn't cover all the background...

You need to put the container on the top of the widget tree to make it as the background.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../components/login_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class LogInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogInPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/login_background.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const Text(
                "Cục An toàn Thông tin",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              const Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/login_logo.png"), width: 80),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const MyTextField(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const MyTextField()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}


omg thank you so much, it works ;-; but the color of the background image is not the same with the root image, what should I do

add following in between Scaffold and body ;
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
